# Setting custom name for raw resource

Tags: android, android-resources

There are a couple of audio mp3 files in `res/raw` which go as prepacked audio files for the app. They all have proper names `...must contain only [a-z0-9_.]` which do not look nice when parsed inside `ListView`.

I see many apps have their custom names for audio. For example, raw file name is "default1" and custom audio name is seen as "The Morning Shine".

How can I set custom name for all custom audios in `res/raw`?

Comment: You want a getting title from song? or you want to use resource like a `R.raw.themorningshine` ?

Comment: Song names and other info are written in META tags **inside the song** files itself. Such meta tags may also include the cover art or the song lyrics.

Comment: @deathember I need a title name from the song. I know how I can get hold of a raw resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these files are static and prepacked as you say, try having an xml resource file that holds custom Strings for each file.

I don't know how you are managing your List, but with a custom Adapter you can link the proper name based on the resource ID.

Other way that maybe could help you is read the Tags directly from the files, with the Class MediaMetadataRetriever.

Example:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(yourFilePath);

String songName=retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

You have other constants like METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, METADATA_KEY_ALBUM and so on for the other fields.
See: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Don't forget to call `retriever.release()` when you're done to free memory.

Good luck.

Comment: I haven't thought about XML resources for them. I will check this.

Comment: I updated my answer with another option you might use, check it out.